# grab url of a image link using jquery click function

Tags: jquery, url, click, href

I'm trying to use jquery and click() to grab the url of an image link once its clicked. The html looks like this.

```
<div class="lp-element lp-pom-image" id="lp-pom-image-167" >
<a href="http://url.com/page" target=""><img src="/image.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

The javascript I'm using so far looks like this but it isn't grabbing the url of the clicked image link. The url needs to be passed to where the variable `this` is.

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery("#lp-pom-image-167").click(function() {
trackOutboundLink(this, 'AddToCart', 'Bottom CTA');
return false;
});
});
```

How do I pull the href url with the appropriate base URI? ie. "http://url.com/page"?

EDIT:clarified what i am trying to pull out.

Comment: `$(this).children("a img").attr('src')` should do the trick.

Comment: `<worried>` Hope you don't intend to copy paste this(any) JS code like this one 200 times for all your `#lp-pom-image-NNN` elements.... `</worried>`

Comment: @Supericy jQuery `.prop` should be used instead of `.attr`.

Comment: @Mooseman please paste an official link where we can read this.

Comment: @roXon According to http://api.jquery.com/prop/, `.attr` only returns initial attributes, and not properties from the DOM. `.prop` will return the current property from the DOM.

Comment: Read [attr vs prop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: @SheikhHeera specially this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7572855/390747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest (though untested):

```
$('.lp-pom-image').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops the default action,
                        // without preventing propagation/bubbling
    trackOutboundLink($(this).find('img').prop('src'), 'AddToCart', 'Bottom CTA');
});
```

Comment: Similar to mine example, but you are using .prop() instad of .attr().  Note: As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Maksym: yes, I know. But thanks for taking the time to point that out. I assumed that he'd want the full URL (hence `prop()`) rather than retrieving a potentially relative URL that might be in the attribute (which he'd get with `attr()`).

Comment: this worked although i switched out find('img') with find('a'). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".lp-pom-image").click(function() {
  console.log($("img", this).attr("src"));
  return false;
});
```

See a working demo at http://jsbin.com/ebicax/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use code below instead of `this` if you want get `a` url:

```
$(this).find("a").attr('href')
```

or this code if u want get `img` src:

```
$(this).find("a img").attr('src')
```